# Android wrap_content programmatically in animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-relativelayout

i working animation.i wrote code witch can slide right laout with animation.it working perfect but i have problem different screen size resolution
this is a my source

```
setAnimation(holder.layoutmain, -400, true);
private void setAnimation(View view, int xCordinnant, boolean close) {
    view.animate().translationX(xCordinnant).setDuration(500)
            .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
}
```

my xml code

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/DBSlideLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="145dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#2e2e2e"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/DBSliderClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:background="@drawable/db_lose" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/counter_plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/DBSliderClose"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="89dp"
        android:background="@drawable/counter_plus" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/counter_minus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/counter_plus"
        android:layout_below="@+id/DBSliderCounter"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"

        android:background="@drawable/count_minus" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DBSliderCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/DBSliderClose"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/counter_plus"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/counter_plus"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="10"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

i slide my layout -400 but large screen resolution  i can not show  perfect my layout.
how i can wrote code to can slide  wrap_content instead of -400?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
anim.setDuration(500);
view.startAnimation(anim);
```